# Zkoss zhtml extra div when using appendchild?

Tags: java, css, zk

My question is related to zkoss and dynamically added components from the Java side.

Whenever I'm using appendchild on any element (like on a Div) it always adds an extra Div as some kind of container. Why is that?

Example, here is a part of a Composer class:

```
...
@Wire("div#myDiv")
private Div testDiv;
...
...
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.setValue("Test");
myLabel.setClass("test-label");
testDiv.appendChild(myLabel)
```

So instead of this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
 <span class="test-label">
...
</span>
</div>
```

I get something like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
 <div id="hj973"> <!--this is the extra div -->
 <span class="test-label">
...
</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

In most cases this is not a problem, except when I'm trying to use the span's as a grid with float, because then of course that div shouldn't be there.

Why is this? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Can you post some demo example so that i can test it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why there is a extra div, but you could write

```
test-label:parent {
 ...
}
```

in your css file so the outer div behaves the way your span
should do now and just ignore span.

If this don't help, I'll check this later, I don't have the time right now.